# How to upload a File to AWS S3 using LWC javascript?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I can upload files like audio, video, image, ppt etc. on AWS S3 using Salesforce Apex, but there is a size limitation while uploading the files using Apex. Therefore I am searching the solutions for uploading the files on AWS S3 with No size limitations, I got that it can be done through javascript. But I am unable to do that in Salesforce. Can anyone help? How to upload a File to AWS S3 using LWC javascript?

Comment: This site isn't a place to get your work done for free. You need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and point out where you are stuck. Don't forget to remove your credentials when you share your code (you do _NOT_ want those to be on display for the entire internet)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload arbitrarily large files in Apex using the [Chunked Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html) API, you just upload it 2.5MB at a time or so. You can upload a file directly with LWC as well, either through the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm) or through a direct connection. You may also find [Authenticating Requests in Browser-Based Uploads Using POST (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html) and its subsequent links to be instrumental in implementing this successfully. Remember that you should not ever expose your AWS secret to the browser, as it is a security risk. The browser-based upload solution allows you to provide a signed request without giving up your secrets, and uploading purely server-side also mitigates that risk. Unfortunately, any solution is going to be several hundred lines of code, so it's infeasible to write an entire solution here. However, I have written some generic AWS code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f) you may find useful as well.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for guiding, will try to implement it.